# Select with where statement in Dynamo DB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

So, I'm using AWS Lambda with node.js to interact with DynamoDB, it's all fine till now cause I can do a scan, query with a primary key, so on.

But, now I need to do a query or scan that I don't know the primary key, I just have the name of the column, the parameter that I want to filter by that column and the table name.

Such as this in SQL language:

```
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_type = 'Moderator';
```

I've searched at the docs, but I still can't do this. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A couple of ways of doing this, depending on how often your app is doing this query and how much you care about performance, I'll start from least effort but least scalable to most effort but most scalable.

1. **Scan table using Filter and projection expressions** - so dynamo shards your data based on partition key and keeps no indexes unless configured.  so the only way to get a comprehensive list of all moderators without any extra table config is to do a full table scan which consumes a lot of IOPS but if this is something thats only occasionally this might be fine. you can add a ["filter expression"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Scan.html#Scan.FilterExpression) to have dynamo return to you only the results where "user_type" = 'Moderator' but in the backend dynamo is still scanning the entire DB, it makes the process a bit faster as the time taken to transfer the results is less but it consumes the same IOPS.. you can go a bit further and use a "projection expression"  to filter only return the "user_name"  field from each row. (this can be helpful if you are dealing with large items. This also doesn't reduce the amount of IOPS consumed but does reduce uneccessary Data returned to you. This method won't scale well though, even if there is only 2 moderators... it will get slower and slower the more users in your DB.
2. **Add a Global Secondary index** this is the middle ground but it also costs, as you need to provision enough IOPS for index to keep up but here things are bit more controlable. you can have a different view of your Table, with a different partition key but note that even for your indexes you need [a partition key that hashes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html) well as its basically anouther table. "user_type" doesn't hash well so what you can do instead is have a field called "moderator_name"  which has the same value as the  "user_name" but only exists on users that are moderators. next you create a secondary index on this field and only moderators will exist in that index. You can then scan this index, to get your moderator list and it won't consume any IOPS on the main table. This may seem a bit hacky but with Dynamo its not like SQL where if you  build a good table structure it can handle any query, you need to specifically build your Dynamo tables to match the kind of reads and writes you expect to perform.. so this leads to the next option
3. **Create a seperate "Moderators" table** This is more work to start but if you are wanting to add moderator specific functionality to your site its probably the better way. If you are doing this I recommend not having a "user_type" in your main table and instead just query this table and if the user exists in it they are a moderator. The reason for this is that without SQL transactions to combine the writes, its likely your  "user_type" field  and your Moderators table will become inconsistent.
4. **Use Dynamo Streams to export your Data to a SQL DB** while Dynamo is great for lots of use cases its not a SQL DB and sacrifices lots of nice and convient SQL features for performance and scalabiility.. Again it might make sense to have your website use Dynamo for speed and but then for creating targeted Email campaigns have the same data in a SQL DB so you can perform complex queries to create email campaigns that target a specific subset of your users.

In different situations I've used all 4 methods, what needs to be stressed is **"...Depends on your use case..."**

Answer (score 5):

DynamoDB is a NoSQL database. The difference between NoSQL databases and traditional Relational (i.e. SQL) databases, is that you get a much faster performance, but that is at the expense of losing your flexibility of running complex queries. If you need to run complex queries on you data, then you should not use DynamoDB, as it is not the right tool for your requirements.

In DynamoDB, you can only run queries over your key attributes. Otherwise, you'll have  to run a scan which returns your entire table and then you can do whatever you want with your data, such as filtering the result.

Every table in DynamoDB usually has at least one key, that is the primary key, also known as Hash Key or Partition Key. But you could also have a Range Key, also known as Sort Key. In your example, if UserType is a sort key, after running the query, DynamoDB will return all rows from all partitions where UserType is equal with 'Moderator'.

But you could also define secondary indexes on your table. Secondary Keys can be either Global Secondary or Local Secondary.This gives you some more flexibility for running queries. See DynamoDB documentation for more details:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/SecondaryIndexes.html

IN SUMMARY: if you don't have control over the design of your DynamoDB table, you're probably stuck with just running a scan. Otherwise, consider redesigning your table indexes and keys to cater for your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Global Secondary Index with user_type as the primary key. Then query from the index.

Comment: Don’t do that... having only a  few “user-types”  will mean that your secondary index will partition horribly and won’t keep up with your main table.

Comment: I've added an answer

Comment: Out of the 4 options what do you recommend @Nath ?

Comment: Depends lots on context, I would need to understood how the query fits in to the app/site design to know which method was appropriate.